# Polynomial Rings 

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ and $S$ be non-zero rings with identity. Is it possible to have $R[x] \cong S[[x]]$ ?

Comment: What about $R=\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, $S=\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: @Piotr: that doesn't work, or at least the natural map isn't an isomorphism. $\mathbb{Z}[[x]] [y]$ is the subring of $\mathbb{Z}[y][[x]]$ in which the coefficients of the $x^n$, as a polynomial in $y$, have uniformly bounded degrees. 

Comment: @Qiaochu: Wow, thanks, I never realized that!

Comment: $S[[x]]$ can be given the structure of a complete metric space, by defining $d(a,b)=2^{-v_x(a-b))}$, with $v_x$ the $x$-adic valuation. On the other hand $R[x]$ is naturally a countable union of quite small subsets (polynomials of degree at most $n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\ldots$. Can one now try to argue topologically using some kind of Baire Category Theorem argument? Not that I can get it to work...

Comment: The notation suggests that you may want to impose that the isomorphism takes $x$ to $x$. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: No, no assumption on where $x$ goes to. 

Comment: I made a similar comment on your other question, but please ammend your title style to include complete questions.  For example, "Can $R[x] \cong S[[x]]$?" is a better title than the current one.  Actually, the entire body of your question would fit in the title — titles on MO may be longer than tweets.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a proof that no such *commutative* rings $R$, $S$ exist. (See the edit for an extension to noncommutative rings.)

Suppose we have an isomorphism $\phi: R[x] \to S[[x]]$; let $a = \phi^{-1}(x)$. First we claim that for all $b \in R[x]$, the element $1 + ab$ is invertible in $R[x]$. Indeed, the element $\phi(1 + ab) = 1 + (\phi(b))x$ has an inverse given by a formal geometric series, so $\phi^{-1}$ applied to this element must also be invertible.

In particular, $1 + ax$ must be invertible in $R[x]$. But it is well-known (in the commutative case) that any invertible polynomial $a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n$ has $a_0$ invertible and the other $a_i$ nilpotent. It follows quickly that $a$ must be nilpotent. But then $\phi(a) = x$ is nilpotent in $S[[x]]$. We have reached an absurdity.

**Edit:** Aided by Martin's excellent suggestion in his comment, we may easily extend the argument to noncommutative rings. Indeed, since $x$ is central in $S[[x]]$, we have that $a$ is central in $R[x]$. In particular, $a$ commutes with scalars; writing $a$ as a polynomial, it follows that each coefficient of $a$ is central in $R$. This is true also of the polynomial $1 + ax$, and now the proof that all but the unit coefficient of $1 + ax$ is nilpotent goes through as in the commutative case (see for example the nice argument given [here](http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/units-in-polynomial-rings/)). Thus $a$ is nilpotent.

Comment: In order to reduce to the commutative case, one may try to compute the centers of $R[x]$ and $S[[x]]$.

Comment: Thanks very much for that suggestion, Martin. I have edited my answer to take it into account. 

Comment: @Todd: Nice solution. Can you generalize this to skew polynomials or Ore extensions !?

Comment: @shatich: perhaps someone else can see such a generalization, but to be honest I had to google Ore extension, so I'd have to sit down and think it over. It might be worth opening another question if you're interested. 

Comment: Another suggestion: In the end of the argument, just *use* the commutative case with $Z(R)[x]$.

Comment: @Martin: Ah, you're right. Maybe I shied away because the center is not functorial on rings and ring homomorphisms. It is however functorial on rings and ring isomorphisms, which is all we need here. 

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Martin Brandenburg suggestion, if $R[x] \cong S[[x]]$ then their centers are isomorphic too. So without loose of generality we can assume that $R$ and $S$ are commutative. In commutative case we know $J(R[x]) = Nil(R[x])$. This means that elements in the Jacobson radical of $R[x]$ are all nilpotent. On the other hand $x \in J(S[[x]])$ and $x$ is not nilpotent. This shows that $R[x]$ and $S[[x]]$ can not be isomorphic.

Comment: In your argument you seem to be assuming that $R[x]$ is Jacobson. There is no reason for this to be true if $R$ is not Jacobson. 

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I cann't see that, could you please tell exactly where he/she used that assumption ??   

Comment: I think Qiaochu's objection arises from $J(R[x])=\mathrm{Nil}(R[x])$. But this, in fact, holds for every commutative ring $R$, and uses the description of the units $R[x]^* = R^* + \mathrm{Nil}(R) (x)$. @tvector: Your proof uses $Z(R[x])=Z(R)[x]$ and $Z(S[[x]])=Z(S)[[x]]$, right?

Comment: @Martin: Exactly, yes. 

Answer (score 0):

Let me write $R[x]=S[[y]]$ to avoid confusion.

I.  Note that 1+y is a unit.  Therefore (thinking of y as an element of $R[x]$), we have $y\in R$.

II.  Now mod out $y$ on both sides:  $\overline{R}[x]=S$.

III. This gives $R[x]=\overline{R}[x][[y]]$

IV.  The ring on the right contains the element $\sum(xy)^n$.  Thus so does the ring on the left (thought of as a subring of the appropriate completion). It follows that $y$ is nilpotent in the ring on the left.  But it's clearly not nilpotent in the ring on the right.  Contradiction.

Comment: I don't think that step I is correct. See also Todd's post for the units of $R[x]$.

Comment: Martin:  Of course you're right.